# Align items in 3's in PHP using HTML

Tags: php, html, css

Good Day All,

I am trying to align  items in a row of 3. At the top of each row there is a div called "". The purpose of this div is to open a new and after every 3 items the div must be close and another one opened. I have tried the below code to my suprise it is not working. This is very weird as the MOD operand should work. Cna any of you see what I could be doing wrong?

The write picture should look like this [image]
It is out of alignment and the blue colour fills the whole page. I do not know what I am doing wrong:

```
$currentRow = 1;
    echo '<div class="top-box">';
    while($Data=mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
        {

         echo '<div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3"> 
           <a href="Single.php?Query='.$Data[5].'">
            <div class="inner_content clearfix">
                <div class="product_image">
                    <img src="images/'.$Data[14].'" height="300" width="320" alt=""/>
                </div>              
                <div class="price">
                   <div class="cart-left">
                        <p class="title">'.$Data[11].'</p>
                        <div class="price1">
                          <span class="actual">R'.$Data[13].'</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-right"> </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                 </div>             
               </div>
             </a>
            </div>';

             $currentRow++;
             if($currentRow % 3 == 0)
             {
                    echo '</div>    ';
                    echo '<div class="top-box">';

             }
        }
```

When I manually repeat the items every 3 items like below, it works perfectly:

```
    <div class="top-box">
      <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
         <a href="Single.php">
         <div class="inner_content clearfix">
            <div class="product_image">
                <img src="images/1st_Party_Boy.jpg" height="300" width="320" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
               <div class="cart-left">
                    <p class="title">His First Party</p>
                    <div class="price1">
                      <span class="actual">R350.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-right"> </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
             </div>             
           </div>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
            <a href="Single.php">
            <div class="inner_content clearfix">
            <div class="product_image">
                <img src="images/Her_First_Party.jpg" height="300" width="320" alt=""/>
            </div>
             <div class="sale-box"><span class="on_sale title_shop">New</span></div>
            <div class="price">
               <div class="cart-left">
                    <p class="title">Her First of Many </p>
                    <div class="price1">
                      <span class="actual">R350.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-right"> </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
             </div>             
           </div>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3">
         <a href="Single.php">
         <div class="inner_content clearfix">
            <div class="product_image">
                <img src="images/First_one_for_boys_and_girls.jpg" height="300" width="320" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
               <div class="cart-left">
                    <p class="title">Their First Birthday</p>
                    <div class="price1">
                      <span class="actual">R350.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-right"> </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
             </div>             
           </div>
         </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey change $currentRow to zero

```
$currentRow = 0;
    echo '<div class="top-box">';
    while($Data=mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
        {

         echo '<div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3"> 
           <a href="Single.php?Query='.$Data[5].'">
            <div class="inner_content clearfix">
                <div class="product_image">
                    <img src="images/'.$Data[14].'" height="300" width="320" alt=""/>
                </div>              
                <div class="price">
                   <div class="cart-left">
                        <p class="title">'.$Data[11].'</p>
                        <div class="price1">
                          <span class="actual">R'.$Data[13].'</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-right"> </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                 </div>             
               </div>
             </a>
            </div>';

             $currentRow++;
             if($currentRow % 3 == 0)
             {
                    echo '</div>    ';
                    echo '<div class="top-box">';

             }
        }
```

Comment: Thans, but it has not made any of a difference. I am so suprised it is not working.